# Playwright SelectOption is not selecting a value

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

When attempting to use page.SelectOption with Playwright, im getting an issue where my chosen value is not being selected, it doesnt matter if I use index, value, or label to try to select.

I know the selector is being found as when I debug using trace viewer I cant see that the step shows:
[image]

However on the select box it doesn't change and acts like it hasn't selected anything.

[image]

code used:
`await page.selectOption('#select', "2");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way of doing the above is:

`const selector = await page.$("#select")`

`await selector?.selectOption("2")`

However the original did work for me, there seems to be a bug with traceviewer where the after shot does not show the selected option.
Github issue raised:

https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/9212

Comment: Bug still existing.